# Getting an error when uploading to Dropbox

Tags: c#, dropbox-api

I am attempting to upload a file to dropbox.

Here is what I have said so far:

```
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(fileName)))
    {
      var numChunks = (int) Math.Ceiling((double) stream.Length / chunkSize);
      var buffer = new byte[chunkSize];
      string sessionId = null;

      if (numChunks == 1)
      {
        using (var memStream = new MemoryStream(buffer, 0, chunkSize))
        {
          Console.WriteLine($"Sending file: {path}");
          var tst = await client.Files.UploadAsync(path, WriteMode.Overwrite.Instance, body: memStream);
        }
      }
      else
      {
        for (var idx = 0; idx < numChunks; idx++)
        {
          Console.WriteLine($"Uploading chunk {idx + 1} / {numChunks}.");
          var byteRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, chunkSize);

          using (var memStream = new MemoryStream(buffer, 0, byteRead))
          {
            if (idx == 0)
            {
              var result = await client.Files.UploadSessionStartAsync(body: memStream);
              sessionId = result.SessionId;
            }

            var cursor = new UploadSessionCursor(sessionId, (ulong) (chunkSize * idx));

            if (idx == numChunks - 1)
            {
              Console.WriteLine($"Finalizing file: {path}");
              var response = await client.Files.UploadSessionFinishAsync(cursor, new CommitInfo(path), memStream);
            }
            else
            {
              await client.Files.UploadSessionAppendV2Async(cursor, body: memStream);
            }
          }
        }
      }

      var url = string.Empty;
      var link = await client.Sharing.ListSharedLinksAsync(path);

      if (link.Links.Count == 0)
      {
        var result = await client.Sharing.CreateSharedLinkWithSettingsAsync(path);
        url = result.Url;
      }
      else
      {
        url = link.Links[0].Url;
      }

      Console.WriteLine();
      Console.WriteLine("Dropbox Download Link:");
      Console.WriteLine(url);
      Console.WriteLine();
      //Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

When I try to send up a large file, I'm getting this message:

[image]

I'm accounting for small and large files. If the file is bigger than the chunksize. I cannot get it to send up the file, I just get an error.

It's happening at this line:

`var response = await client.Files.UploadSessionFinishAsync(cursor, new CommitInfo(path), memStream);`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Looking at the innerException it seems that the stream is 'closed'. Since you're awaiting your task like you should i cannot see any possibility of the stream disposing by another thread or something. This still looks  Perhaps you can test my theory and remove the using from memstream as a test?

Comment: Is it possible that the reason is in missing [this `else` line](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/blob/b5dff871d353c46dcdf61f0319a10be4ed0b8c0c/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/Examples/SimpleTest/Program.cs#L497) in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't run it locally and didn't use Dropbox's client but I see the following...

1. Probably, while slow manual debugs you can miss the issue.
2. Expect, that the error message is *slightly* misleading. In general, it is right. But there should be an additional check to catch a case when *your original Stream was changed*.
3. Let me add more sync/async chaos data about 'what the hell is happening here?!.'. At first, your `for` runs synchronously - all upload sessions start in parallel in a short period of time. **At second, each of `for`s has its own `block-level scope` that has the `using (...) {...}` syntax sugar in the sync context.** All `var memStream`s are covering each other in the upper sync context. Then, every thread does its work in its own async context. Take a look at the `var response`. It is a loop variable and it is not in use in your main SYNC context. **It is not declared out of the `using` closure.** So this line can be not awaitable in the sync context. In this case `using` will finish when the `memStream` will be consumed but `UploadSessionFinishAsync` will be working still.
4. Why it happens only at `var response = await client.Files.UploadSessionFinishAsync(cursor, new CommitInfo(path), memStream);`? Think, it could be the issue in each `await client.Files...` call but only `client.Files.UploadSessionFinishAsync` tries to do something with the passed `memStream`. For example, close it as a final step. Or process the `memStream`, abandoned the stream, do another work such as a request to Dropbox to get a final upload result.
5. Idea about the fix. I think you need to declare the final result `var response` above the `for` scope. Then just set the result at the last chunk processing. In this case `using` will have to wait for its result, only then it could dispose `memStream`. Just like with `sessionId = result.SessionId;`. Or just explicitly wait for its result before the `using` end.
6. Code optimization. For a short file you don't need `buffer` and `sessionId`. They are for multiple uploading threads. For a big file - return the `UploadSessionFinishAsync` result from your loop. Maybe, declare multiple `memStream`s as different vars. Not sure about `UploadSessionAppendV2Async` result. If it is `void` then it is OK. Otherwise, such a result also should be awaited. It could be like this:

```
//outer vars
SomeDropboxFileUploadResultOrElse uploadResult;
string sessionId = null;

//original full file read
using (var stream = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(fileName)))
{
   var numChunks = (int) Math.Ceiling((double) stream.Length / chunkSize);
   if (numChunks == 1)
   {
       Console.WriteLine($"Sending file: {path}");
       uploadResult = await client.Files.UploadAsync(path, WriteMode.Overwrite.Instance, body: stream);
   }
   else
   {
       var buffer = new byte[chunkSize];
       for (var idx = 0; idx < numChunks; idx++)
       {
           Console.WriteLine($"Uploading chunk {idx + 1} / {numChunks}.");
           var byteRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, chunkSize);

           using (var memStream = new MemoryStream(buffer, 0, byteRead))
           {
               if (idx == 0)
               {
                   var result = await client.Files.UploadSessionStartAsync(body: memStream);
                   sessionId = result.SessionId;
               }
               //prevent 2+ parts processing on idx == 0 iteration, start thread in the sync scope but wait for sessionId value in the async thread
               else
               {
                   var cursor = new UploadSessionCursor(sessionId, (ulong)(chunkSize * idx));
                   if (idx == numChunks - 1)
                   {
                       Console.WriteLine($"Finalizing file: {path}");
                       //explicitly pass result to outer scope, then the execution could be continued, memStream could be closed below
                       uploadResult = await client.Files.UploadSessionFinishAsync(cursor, new CommitInfo(path), memStream);
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       await client.Files.UploadSessionAppendV2Async(cursor, body: memStream);
                   }
               }
           } //memStream?.Dispose(); 
       }
   }
...
}
```

Hope, this will help.

Answer (score 1):

For the first chunk `idx==0` you have to call only `UploadSessionStartAsync` and you also call `UploadSessionAppendV2Async`. Try this:

```
...
using (var memStream = new MemoryStream(buffer, 0, byteRead))
{
    if (idx == 0)
    {
        var result = await client.Files.UploadSessionStartAsync(body: memStream);
          sessionId = result.SessionId;
    }
    else
    {
        var cursor = new UploadSessionCursor(sessionId, (ulong) (chunkSize * idx));

        if (idx == numChunks - 1)
        {
          Console.WriteLine($"Finalizing file: {path}");
          var response = await client.Files.UploadSessionFinishAsync(cursor, new CommitInfo(path), memStream);
        }
        else
        {
          await client.Files.UploadSessionAppendV2Async(cursor, body: memStream);
        }
    }
}
...
```